# Not sure about the validity of the query

Tags: sql

I would like to write an sql join query which retrieves the product number and supplier numbers of all unique pairs of suppliers who supply the same product, along with their product purchase prices.

Columns are:

SUPPLIER (**SUPNR**, SUPNAME, SUPADDRESS, SUPCITY, SUPSTATUS)

PRODUCT (**PRODNR**, PRODNAME, PRODTYPE, AVAILABLE_QUANTITY)

SUPPLIES (***SUPNR, PRODNR***, PURCHASE_PRICE, DELIV_PERIOD)

PURCHASE_ORDER (**PONR**, PODATE, SUPNR)

PO_LINE (***PONR****,* ***PRODNR***, QUANTITY)

NOTE: (primary keys are BOLD, foreign keys are bold in italics

my code is:

```
SELECT S1.SUPNR, S2.SUPNR, S2.PRODNR, S2.PURCHASE_PRICE
FROM SUPPLIES S1, SUPPLIES S2
WHERE S1.SUPNR > S2.SUPNR
```

Is it a correct query?

Comment: If you want to write a join, write a JOIN. The TableA, TableB syntax has been obsolete for more than 25 years now.

Comment: But still this syntax is widely used in cloud especially for Datawarehousing sqls eg Aws redshift. Thats true that here its not recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just need to add `PRODNR`

```
 SELECT S1.SUPNR, S2.SUPNR, S2.PRODNR, 
  S2.PURCHASE_PRICE
  FROM SUPPLIES S1 join SUPPLIES S2
  On S1.SUPNR > S2.SUPNR and
  S1.Prodnr=s2.prodnr
```

Comment: it gives me the error. i have added distinct                                                                     
SELECT DISTINCT S1.SUPNR, S2.SUPNR, S2.PRODNR, S2.PURCHASE_PRICE
FROM SUPPLIES S1, SUPPLIES S2
WHERE S1.SUPNR > S2.SUPNR

Comment: Whats the error

Comment: I got fixed the error. you missed S2 in front of the PRODNR. THANKS